# Catalog viewer in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm currently working on a flutter app and would like to make it possible to upload catalogs and brochures. I would like to be able to set click events on the products when uploading the catalog, which should then ultimately lead to the fact that you can click on a product in the catalog viewer and thus get to the detail view. Does anyone have an idea how to implement something like that? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Widgets like ListView or GridView to show your items (catalogs) and navigate on a tap even to a new page with you desired detail.

To familiarize yourself with the Flutter Basics checkout their [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/).

To learn more about widgets that might suit your application check out the [WidgetCatalog](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets). Here the layout section might be of interest (see examples above).

To learn more about navigation check out this [Flutter Cookbook](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation).